# What happened to my save?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I was playing GTA yesterday (I've beaten the main game) and did a few Strangers and Freaks missions and went to bed. While I was doing it, I clicked the home button to check on a download and noticed my time was wrong so I changed it. When I got on, nothing I had done up to that point was saved and it brought me all the way back to the part in the story where Franklin saved Michael from the Asian gang. I'm not online. Where did my save go?

Comment: I don't think stranger and freak missions get saved automatically, I could be wrong about this. But if they don't, then your game might have lost its progress because you changed the time.

Comment: But why would it be to that specific point?

Comment: How long ago was the specific save that you were returned to?

Comment: 19 days ago. Thats what it says on the save

Comment: But it also says that i saved the samething today on autosave for some reason

Comment: After a quick google, it seems that this is not a stand alone problem. What could have happened is that the game reloaded on your 19 day old save and then auto saved over your actual last save...

Comment: So I wont be able to retrive it?

Comment: If my theory is correct, then your save is most likely lost. I don't think there is any `convert to last save` function on console. Sorry for your loss :(

Comment: Its okay. On the bright side though i get to do the other options om the heists! Thank you very much for your help